# iOS: Reachability - startNotifier fails after returning to app

Tags: ios, ios7, reachability

I have Reachability working exactly as suggested as in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/92153).

I am using the [open source Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability). However I am not using blocks but notifications, hence the process is pretty similar to the Apple's Reachability code.

The first time I start the app, I run this and it works great.

```
Reachability *reachability = [reach hostReachability];
[reachability startNotifier];
```

The reachabilityChanged: event is firing:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachability_Changed:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

However once I press the home button and come back to the app, the `startNotifier` returns internally a NO instead of a YES.

```
    // Set it as our reachability queue, which will retain the queue
    if(!SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(self.reachabilityRef, self.reachabilitySerialQueue))
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue() failed: %s", SCErrorString(SCError()));
#endif
      ...
      return NO;
```

and hence the event above is never fired again.

Unless I am using this wrongly and `startNotifier` should only be called once in `init` when reachability is instantiated and never again?

```
self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:_HOST];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only need to call `[self.hostReachability startNotifier]` once on init/load. Here's a rundown of your basic needs, using notifications rather than the block method on the linked thread:

1. Add the [tonymillion/Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) library to your project.
2. Create property for your Reachability object to make sure it's retained, eg.

   ```
   @interface ViewController () {
     NSString *_HOST;
   }
   @property Reachability *hostReachability;
   @end
   ```
3. Register for change notifications, and start the notifier, eg.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                  name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                object:nil];

     _HOST = @"www.google.com";
     self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:_HOST];
     [self.hostReachability startNotifier];
   }

   - (void)viewDidUnload
   {
     [super viewDidUnload];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
   }
   ```
4. Finally, create a `reachabilityChanged:` method to handle your response to Reachability changes, eg.

   ```
   - (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
   {
     Reachability *notifier = [notification object];
     NSLog(@"%@", [notifier currentReachabilityString]);
   }
   ```

Note: If you press the Home button and unload the app, changes in Reachability should fire a notification immediately upon returning to the app.