# Reachability and reachabilityWithHostName

Tags: ios, reachability, network-state

I am using iOS 7.1 (XCode 5.1) and recently downloaded Tony Million's Reachability library and later [Apples example code](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). When testing, both successfully detected when i turned WiFi off, however upon reconnection the hostname remained unreachable.

> Trying to identify why I looked at HTTP traffic and it appears that the remoteHostName is       no longer being used and instead three randomized hostname requests (eg. `http://jcyoxhjblg`).
>
> **Edit** The above statement is incorrect, it appears these three connections are not related to reachability [but a Chrome DNS feature](https://mikewest.org/2012/02/chrome-connects-to-three-random-domains-at-startup) which executes on reconnection. I am still looking into why it remains unreachable on reconnection.

I have tested from both sample codes (apple's excerpt below) on the local simulator with both www.apple.com and www.google.com (with and without http://). Both deliver the results shown/mentioned above.

Am I missing some basic understanding of how hostname reachability is provided from within Reachability ?

```
NSString *remoteHostName = @"www.google.com";
self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:remoteHostName];
[self.hostReachability startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.hostReachability];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should initial another Reachability object and call "[self.hostReachability startNotifier]" everytime your app wake from background, because method "startNotifier" depends on whether CurrentRunloop is running.

Comment: this question may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361274/ios-reachability-startnotifier-fails-after-returning-to-app